# How can I get a multidimensional array to loop with string input?

Tags: java

Basically I'm making a program that reads from a multidimensional array to display it's corresponding information. What I want to do is make it so the while loop will continue to tell me I'm putting in the wrong class ID's until you put in a correct Class ID.

do
        {

```
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of your course to display it's information");
    name = input.nextLine();

    for(int x = 0; x <= classes.length; ++x)
    {

        if(name.equals(classes[x][0]))
        {

            i = true;

            System.out.println("Course info: " + classes [x][0]);
            System.out.println(classes[x][1]);
            System.out.println(classes[x][2]);
            x = classes.length;


        }

        else{

            System.out.println("Wrong course id");
            i = false;
            input.next();

            }   
    }
    }

    while (!(i));
    System.out.println("This is the end of the program!");
    System.exit(0);
```

Comment: `x <= classes.length` will give an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I see that now, is there any good way to rewrite this so I don't get that error?

Comment: `x < classes.length`

Comment: I gave that a try and it seems to be giving me the same result. When I go to execute the program if I feed it incorrect data it goes to the else then just loops at the else saying "Wrong course id" even if I put in the correct one.

Comment: That has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to keep good naming conventions. `i` is bad name for a flag variable. Name it `boolean found` or something. It will not only help other people read and understand your code, but it will help you in order find the logic you have to use as well.

Now, since you have `input.next();` in `else` part, i guess you want to ask again for user input, until a something is found. So, a `name = input.nextLine();` is required again in order to take new input. But in your case the `else` part can be removed completely and let the `do-while` do the work.

An example:

```
public class Classes {
    private static final String[][] CLASSES = { { "Maths", "info" }, { "History", "info" }, { "Biology", "info" } };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean found = false;
        String name;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of your course to display it's information");
            name = input.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < CLASSES.length; i++) {
                if (name.equals(CLASSES[i][0])) {
                    found = true;
                    System.out.println("Course info: " + CLASSES[i][0]);
                    System.out.println(CLASSES[i][1]);
//                  System.out.println(CLASSES[i][2]); //My CLASSES array, does not have 3 columns
                    break;// exit for loop
                }
            }
            if (!found)
                System.out.println("Wrong course id");
        } while (!found);
        input.close();
        System.out.println("This is the end of the program!");
    }
}
```